# error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token

Tags: c, shell, compiler-errors

I am working on a simple shell project and i had the main loop working. I could input commands and it would parse the string.  I also had a which command working.  I made some small changes and now i get the error:

```
sh.c: In function ‘which’:
sh.c:15: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
sh.c:85: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
sh.c:92: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
sh.c:97: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘{’ token
sh.h:6: error: old-style parameter declarations in prototyped function definition
sh.c:100: error: expected ‘{’ at end of input
make: *** [sh.o] Error 1
```

Below is my sh.c file. I tried entirely removing my which code because i though that was the issue. But it changed nothing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include "sh.h"

int sh( int argc, char **argv, char **envp )
{
  char *prompt = calloc(PROMPTMAX, sizeof(char));
  char *commandline = calloc(MAX_CANON, sizeof(char));
  char *command, *arg, *commandpath, *p, *pwd, *owd;
  char **args = calloc(MAXARGS, sizeof(char*));
  int uid, i, status, argsct, go = 1;
  struct passwd *password_entry;
  char *homedir;
  struct pathelement *pathlist;

  uid = getuid();
  password_entry = getpwuid(uid);               /* get passwd info */
  homedir = password_entry->pw_dir;     /* Home directory to startout with*/

  if ( (pwd = getcwd(NULL, PATH_MAX+1)) == NULL )
  {
    perror("getcwd");
    exit(2);
  }
  owd = calloc(strlen(pwd) + 1, sizeof(char));
  memcpy(owd, pwd, strlen(pwd));
  prompt[0] = ' '; 
  prompt[1] = '\0';

  /* Put PATH into a linked list */
  pathlist = get_path();

  while ( go )
  {
    /* print your prompt */
    printf(" [%s]>", getcwd(NULL, PATH_MAX+1));
    /* get command line and process */
      fgets(commandline, MAX_CANON, stdin);

    printf("in commandline %s", commandline);

    args[0] = strtok(commandline, " \n");
    int n = 0;
    printf ("in args %s;\n", args[0]);
    while(args[n]!=NULL){
      n++;
      args[n] = strtok(NULL, " \n");
      printf ("in args %s;\n", args[n]);
    }



    /* check for each built in command and implement */
    if(strcmp(args[0], "exit") == 0){
      printf("exiting\n");
      exit(0);
    }

    if(strcmp(args[0], "which") == 0){
      which(args, pathlist);

    }

  }
  return 0;
} /* sh() */

int which(char **args, struct pathelement *pathlist )
{
  return 0;
}



char *where(char *command, struct pathelement *pathlist )
{
  /* similarly loop through finding all locations of command */
} /* where() */

void list ( char *dir )
{
  /* see man page for opendir() and readdir() and print out filenames for
  the directory passed */
} /* list() */
```

Below is my sh.h file

```
#include "get_path.h"

int pid;
int sh( int argc, char **argv, char **envp);
int which(char **args, struct pathelement *pathlist )
char *where(char *command, struct pathelement *pathlist);
void list ( char *dir );
void printenv(char **envp);

#define PROMPTMAX 32
#define MAXARGS 10
```

I know it is probably some silly mistake like missing a semicolon or a bracket.  But I've gone through all of the code a few times and can't seem to find it.

Comment: int which(char **args, struct pathelement *pathlist )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without all the code it's hard to see all the errors and the line corresponding. But in your `sh.h` file I already see that you're missing an `;` after the line `int which(char **args, struct pathelement *pathlist )`.